# Como chamar o método de uma classe dentro de outra(bluej)

Tags: java

Eis aqui o que tenho feito

```
public void valorConta(){
    int i=0;
    float totalConta=0;
    for(i=0;i<listaligacoes.length;i++){
    totalConta+=(listaligacoes[i].calcularDuracao()*listaligacoes[i].getvalor());
}
}
```

Tenho uma variavel listaligacao do Tipo Ligacao(classe) gostaria de nela, chamar os metodos calcular duracao e valor, para setar o valor da conta nesta classe atual.
Uso o bluej.

Comment: Só pra deixar mais claro, eu sou iniciante, tem muito termo que não entendo ainda.

Answer (score 1):

Use static...

```
public static void valorConta(){
    int i=0;
    float totalConta=0;
    for(i=0;i<listaligacoes.length;i++){
       totalConta+=(listaligacoes[i].calcularDuracao()*listaligacoes[i].getvalor());
    }
}
```

Pra chamar em outra classe é simples

`NomeDaClasseQueTemOMetodo.valorConta();`

Lembrando que dessa forma `listaligacoes` precisa ser uma variavel *static*, ou você pode receber ela como Parametro, e da forma ali de cima você nao retorna nada... Se quiser retornar *totalConta* troca `void` por `int`

Comment: O problema é que se esse vetor `listaligacoes` não for estático isso não irá funcionar. Seria melhor você citar isso. Pois se esse vetor pertencer ao objeto, ou precisar pertencer ao objeto... essa solução não funcionará.

Comment: Essa função `valorConta` poderia receber essa lista no parâmetro.

Comment: Eu pensei nesse problema tbm.,.. Mas acho que foge um pouco da Pergunta do cara, mas... Vou colocar ali na resposta então

Comment: Sim.. foge um pouco mesmo. Faltou ela detalhar melhor a pergunta.